# We can call a web-app running on Docker to check if it's working with Postman?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, postman

i'm started to using Docker for a better understanding of how the containers work. I started some web-apps on docker, created from java.jar projects and i wanted to test them in Postman, using GET/POST/DELETE etc, but i don't know how? I tried to connect my web browser to that container web-app ip and it's working to see greeting messages, for example, but in postman, nop. We can do something about that or it's container job to do that and we need to test with Postman before we make a Docker container that app?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11

EXPOSE 8080

ADD target/boys-revenind.jar boys-revenind.jar


#Execute the program
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/boys-revenind.jar"]
```

Docker build:

```
>docker build -t boys-revenind.jar .
```

Docker run:

```
>docker run -p 9090:8080 boys-revenind.jar
...starting Spring Boot app
```

Java-Controller:

```
@RestController


public class EchipaController {
    @GetMapping("/greet")
    public String returnGreeet()
    {   return "Hello from Docker";}
```

But now, if i want to go to: `http://localhost:9090/greet -> localhost refused to connect, if i use the docker-machine ip it's working, but just that, not in Postman... 192.168.99.100:9090/greet -> the only way i can see the greet message

Edited with images:

```
-using machine-ip-address with port specified in docker run -p 9090:8080
```

### [image]

```
-using localhost:with port specified in docker run -p 9090:8080
```

[image]

And my build in docker-console:
[image]

Postman doesn't work with neither of the ip's...
[image]

Comment: Postman should be able to reach the container the same way the browser can.

Comment: There's nothing here we can use to help--if one client (e.g., browser) can reach your web app then anything should be able to.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "to that container web-app ip"?  You should be using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as the host name/IP that you are connecting to.  The port number you should use is a function of how you're mapping ports when you launch your container via `docker run ...`.  So, in short, make sure you're using the same address like `127.0.0.1:<portnum>` in both your browser and in Postman.  There's no reason that one should work and not the other.

Comment: If what has been said so far doesn't help you resolve this issue, please provide us with the URL that you are accessing in your browser and what you think is the equivalent Postman setup.  The only reason for one client to work but not the other is if these two sets of data are not equivalent.  You should be able to create a GET in PostMan, use the same URL, and get back the same response that your browser is receiving.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answers! I started again my docker container and nada, i edited with some prints for Dockerfile, controller and build, i'm sure  i do something wrong, but i don't know what... i use localhost:9090/echipa/greeting in webapp to see the greeting message but "refused to connect"... what can i do?

Comment: Please post text as text, not images of text :)

Comment: Sorry, sorry, sorry, sorry, i did that now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any issues with testing the api in postman, even if it is inside a container. The container port should be linked to the host's when it was started. For example: `docker run -p 8080:8080 username/image:tag`.

When you run this, it connects the computer's port 8080 to the containers port 8080 and runs it seemingly like a native application.

If you are able to see the message in a web browser, you should be able to get the same with a get request from postman. You mentioned you were using the containers ip; use the host ip instead.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for your answer! I edited this post to show some prints at what i'm currently doing... not so great, i guess i do something wrong, i watched a tutorial yesterday and the greeting message worked then, i started again with the same example but with some test (post, delete) to use in Postman, but i can't reach the web, and i don't know why. Please tell me what i should do!

Comment: With the above information, there seems to be no reason that this should be happening. If you use the browser to hit the url, postman should be able to do the same with a get request. Is there any other information that you can provide such as postman error screenshot or the rest of the spring boot console output?

Comment: Hello agains and thanks for your time! I did the same as this guy did: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3YERpG2rMs&list=PLVz2XdJiJQxzMiFDnwxUDxmuZQU3igcBb&index=2, i can access the docker-ip-machine:portsetted in -p 9090:8080/greet, but if i use localhost:9090/greet it doesn't work, i'm going to update the post with prints to see, please respond!

Comment: Hello again, it work's now, but i don't know how? I just stoped because of frustration and going outside for a walk and now it's working, the Postman, the call from web, i still can't connect my maven plugin to java and docker because error on localhost on TLS and i don't have that TLS option to enable on my laptop, but it's a different story, thanks!

Comment: Hello agains... i find out a strange thing... if i use EXPOSE 8080 as a port and then another one in run list -p 1010:8080 it's working, but if i use EXPOSE 1010 or EXPOSE 9090 it doesn't work, and i don't know why is happening like that... it's because Tomcat is by default 8080?

Comment: Yes, by default tomcat runs on port 8080. So if no tomcat configurations are set then the application will be exposed on port 8080. Using the run command as described will connect the container port 8080 to the host's put 1010 and will expose it to the outside world via the host ip and port number.

Answer (score 0):

i find out a strange thing... if i use EXPOSE 8080 as a port and then another one in run list -p 1010:8080 it's working, but if i use EXPOSE 1010 or EXPOSE 9090 it doesn't work, and i don't know why is happening like that... it's because Tomcat is by default 8080?